# Asset application.css is not declared but it is declared in manifest

Tags: sprockets, ruby-on-rails-5.1, rails-sprockets

I got this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Asset `application.css` was not declared to be precompiled in production.
Declare links to your assets in `app/assets/config/manifest.js`.

  //= link application.css
and restart your server):
```

- Rails 5.1.4
- sprockets (4.0.0.beta5, 4.0.0.beta4, 3.7.1)
- sprockets-rails (3.2.1, 3.2.0, 2.3.3)

**Manifest.js**

```
//= link_tree ../images

//= link_directory ../javascripts .js

//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
```

**Assets.rb**

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

# Add additional assets to the asset load path.
# Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Emoji.images_path
# Add Yarn node_modules folder to the asset load path.
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')

# Precompile additional assets.
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in the app/assets
# folder are already added.
# Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js admin.css )
```

**Application.rb**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Comment: Also getting this quite suddenly on rails 5.1.7

Comment: Just got this out of nowhere on rails 6.0.2.1

Answer (score 3):

Got this too after changing renaming `application.css` to `application.scss`.

The fix is easy enough, just make your manifest.js file look like this:

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link application.css
```

Restart the server and hopefully that will fix it. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rake tmp:clear`. It helped me.